# Kendo grid invokes read method on empty grid when column is clicked in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a grid which loads data after search button is clicked. However i am running into the issue where when the user clicks on any of the column, it tends to call datasource read function. 
 Is there anyway to stop invoking read method when the column is clicked and only call the read function when search button is clicked?

Razor:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeName, new { @class = "col-sm-4 control-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeName, new { @class = "form-control"})           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
            <input id="btnSearch" type="submit" value="Search" class="btn" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Portal.EmployeeViewModel>()
    .Name("GridEmployeeInvitation")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.EmployeeNumber).Width("160px");
        columns.Bound(e => e.EmployeeName).Width("180px");              
    })
    .Excel(excel => excel
        .FileName("File.xlsx")
        .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Shared"))
        .AllPages(true)
    )           
    .Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(new object[] { 10, 20, 50, 100, "All" }))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Selectable()
    .Sortable(sortable => sortable
        .AllowUnsort(true)
        .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
    .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(322))
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                    .Extra(false)
                    .Operators(operators => operators
                        .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                            .Contains("Contains")
                            .StartsWith("Starts with")
                            .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                            .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to"))))
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(10)
                .ServerOperation(false)
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetEmployees", "Admin").Data("GetSearchParameters"))
                )
)


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnSearch').click(function (e) {
        ('#GridEmployeeInvitation').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
    });

    function GetSearchParameters() {
        return { employeeName: $("#EmployeeName").val()            
           };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The reason for this is the Sortable option, the grid needs to refresh for the new sorting to happen. Not sure you can keep the Sortable option while disabling your issue.

Comment: @MarioGarcia sure that makes sense. but what doesn't is why try to refresh when there is no data in the grid?? anyway to only enable sorting when grid has data.